# Python3 Tweet Sorting Not Working

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on a small project in Python using Tweepy. 
The purpose of the code is to sort tweets. If a tweet contains a word from my list it is saved in a positive file else in the negative file.

Also I'm not interested in replies or retweets.

I've tried two different approaches the latest one is with .find(). I don't get it. When i grab a tweet as a string and grab a word from it as a string and use the function it does the job.

But in my script it always returns -1. Any tips and ideas are welcome. Btw I'm a noob in python.

```
class SortedTweet(object):
tweet_text = ""
is_positive = False
is_retweeted = False
is_reply = False
created_at = None
id = ""

def __init__(self, tweet, is_positive):
    self.tweet_text = tweet.full_text
    self.created_at = tweet.created_at
    self.is_retweeted = hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status') is True
    self.is_reply = tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None
    self.is_positive = is_positive
    self.id = tweet.id_str

def sort_tweets(currentTweetList):
with open('list.txt','r') as keyword_file:
    for keyword in keyword_file:
        for tweet in currentTweetList:
           s = tweet.tweet_text.lower()
           if ((s.find(keyword) != -1) & (tweet.is_reply == False) & (tweet.is_retweeted == False)):
                tweet.is_positive = True
return currentTweetList
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the command .strip() because every time it read a line it included the "enter" as well. So no wonder there were no matches.